# How to host neo4j service in azure vm and access it from anywhere(local computer)?

Tags: azure, ubuntu, neo4j, azure-virtual-machine

Recently, I have deployed an Ubuntu OS VM in azure portal. I am able to run the neo4j service inside the VM but not able to access it from my local computer. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to do so?

Comment: hey even i need same help did you find the solution ????

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this guide: https://www.techuz.com/blog/installing-neo4j-ubuntu-14-04-step-step-guide/.

In the end, add the inbound rule for port:7474 and 7687 in Azure NSG

[image]

Comment: hi I follower you steps in centos 8 azure vm. But I am not able to access the neo4j in local using ip address